Black Duck Detect 9 - Exclude npm dev dependencies
I have recently updated from black duck detect version 6.9.1 to 9.0.0.
Previously in order to exclude dev dependencies from the list of components in the scan results from package.json and package-lock.json.
I would set the property:
--detect.npm.include.dev.dependencies=false

But based on my research this is depreciated. Is there a new way of doing this that currently works?

According to the documentation, You should try this setting:
--detect.npm.dependency.types.excluded=DEV
